# Move Gradle task under verification

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle, spotbugs

I have a task configure, spotbugs.  It is under the other task list.  Can I move it to show under verification and run when check runs?  I am using intellij

Comment: No, it is not possible. The IDE shows this structure, based on the tasks graph which build the Gradle itself.